# Refresh tokens and JWT tokens Interaction

Tags: security, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, refresh-token

I am building an application using JWT for authentication. I started doing some research and I am surprised by the lack of consensus about topics such as refresh tokens and storage for tokens.

As far as I can see JWT and OAuth are two different protocols and they follow 
different specifications.

OAuth uses a refresh token in order to get a new access token but in order to do so, there are 4 entities involved in the process, The User (The Front-end), The Resource Server (Facebook, Google, etc), The Client Server (e.g PHP Web Application) and the Authorisation Server.

In that case, it makes sense to have a refresh token because in order to refresh the token, it is required a client id and a client secret (issued by the Resource/Auth Server) which is known only by the Client Server and not by the User (User front end Side). So the refresh token would be useless for an attacker who stole the refresh token.

But my question is, for an application which is not authenticated against a third party Resource Server such as Google, Facebook and so on, Is it really useful to have a refresh token, why don't make the JWT token last as long as a refresh token.

On the other hand, I could see that when a refresh token is used along with a JWT token as [This Article](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/) states, the refresh tokens are usually subject to strict storage requirements to ensure they are not leaked. However, I could not find What/Where and How I can store this token on the User side in order to meet those strick storage requirements.

Can someone please enlighten me about all of this? Thanks.

Note: I want to highlight that my web app is NOT using third party application to authenticate (Facebook, Google etc), it is Single Page App in the front-end side and in the server side a single API which issue a JWT token. My questions are focused on this kind of architecture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you are right, if you store the refresh and access tokens the same way, and your app itself is the identity provider, it doesn't make much sense to use a refresh token - it can be stolen the same way as the actual access token.

However, consider two things.

One, the access token is sent with every request. If you look at recent (and older) https vulnerabilities, it may be possible sometimes for an external attacker to extract bits of the https stream (under certain circumstances, depending on the specific vulnerability). This is usually not straightforward, and probably not possible on every request. If you have a short lived access token and a longer lived refresh token that is rarely used, even if the access token is compromised through such an ssl/tls attack, the refresh token might not be. This is a very slight benefit, but still.

Also, you can potentially store the refresh token differently. One of the main risks to these tokens is XSS. If you implement your identity provider in a way that it issues refresh tokens in httpOnly cookies, then the refresh token cannot be accessed by Javascript, so XSS cannot be used to read it. You can still store the access token in a Javascript object or localStorage or whatever, and if it's compromised, it is at least short lived. This is good, because XSS usually requires user interaction, so if it worked once, because for example the user clicked a link or visited a particular page, it is not guaranteed that he will do it again, so reading the next access token may be difficult for an attacker. Again, it's not a huge benefit, but it *is* an advantage.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good answer and relevant points to consider.

Answer (score -1):

JWT tokens should have a limited lifetime to limit their usefulness in case they're stolen. Refresh tokens are used to get new access tokens without involving the user and should only be used from a confidential client.

I describe the OAuth2 flows and use of refresh tokens in more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31768524/18044).

Comment: Well thanks but it does not answer my question. If both the access tokens and the refresh token are stored on the client side and if an access token can be stolen what stop an attacker to steal a refresh token. Therefore, if a refresh token can be stolen as well why don't just use only an access token with long lifetime.

Comment: It depends on what you mean with client. In OAuth speak, the app accessing the user's resource is the client. If it's a confidential client (i.e. runs on a server or trusted environment), it can use a refresh token. If it's a JavaScript app or an app from your phone's app store, it cannot use a refresh token.

Comment: Exactly that is my point, as a stated in my question, my web app is NOT using third party application to authenticate (facebook, google etc), what i meant by client in the previous comment is the front- end side and the server who issue the JWT is my back-end side. So, now with that environment architecture, Should i use a refresh token to refresh my JWT token? How can it help me to make my app more secure? Where I should saved that refresh token? Should I only use a long life access token?

Comment: And as stated in the answer I linked to and in my comments, NO. If your front-end is not a confidential client, you should not use refresh tokens as there's no way to secure them.

Comment: and so what options do i have to avoid the users to authenticate again everytime the JWT token expires. Imagine is the JWT token is a short-lived token, that would be a nightmare for them. I could not match any of your grant types (on your other thread-answer) to my current scenario.

Comment: Some identity providers establish cookie sessions between client and authorization server and allow the client to refresh JWT tokens while the cookie session is valid. But it depends on what identity provider you'd want to use.